# Formatting lowest line by using End(xlUp)

Tags: vba, excel

I used a macro as a reference and created this code to select and format the last line of text. I am however getting a syntax error. Any insight on how this can be resolved would be appreciated.

```
Dim Title As String
Title = "C. TEST PROCEDURE"
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B56").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1) = Title
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A56").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Select
Selection.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
Selection.Font.Bold = True
```

Comment: The code executes fine on my machine.  Could you post which line the error occurs on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `Selection` demands that you keep your worksheet e.g `Sheet1` active. If you have another sheet activated and run the code you will get error. `Selection` is poor choice in VBA.

Try this

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A56").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0)
.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
.Font.Bold = True
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You code works with proper data.

Starting with:

[image]

Your code produces:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Code ran without any syntax errors, but if you are looking to format the last line, the following works for me

```
Dim Title As String, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Title = "C. TEST PROCEDURE"
ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1) = Title
ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Select
Selection.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
Selection.Font.Bold = True
```

I'm not sure if there was anything significant about row 56, but this will get the last row used in the column.

Comment: If you're not going to change sheets, there's not much need in setting an object variable. You could use a `With ActiveSheet` block instead to avoid using the `ws` variable.

Comment: I agree. But there are many ways to reference the sheet. It's just how i had it in my gist. If you're not going to change sheets, you don't even need to specify `sheets("Sheet1")`. If you think it would greatly improve the answer, I invite you to make the edit. I'll even give you the 2 points (though with your reputation, i guess you get them anyway).

Comment: No need to edit, the code works it was just a comment. (You don't get points once you have edit privileges ;) )